# Criteria .list() is not returning all records

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I'm working with a table containing 17 records.

Using `session.createCriteria(MyTable.class).list()`, it returns only 6 records;

Using `session.createQuery("from MyTable")`, it returns all records.

The same to `.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE").list`.

I really don't know what i'm missing.

Oh, and i'm using Hibernate 4.2.2 directly. No Spring or any framework.

## SOLUTION

Hibernate created a query with a inner join. I was missing to configure `Fetch.LAZY` on the mapping.

Comment: Have you looked at the generated SQL from the criteria query?

Comment: Yes, i looked and found that hibernate created a query with a inner join. I was missing to configure "Fetch.LAZY" on the mapping. LAZY was me. :/ Thank you anyway!

Comment: It shouldn't create an inner join, but a left join. Unless you told it that the association is mandatory although it's actually optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U need to look up at the Lazy Loading Concepts and ya U can give Configuration of Lazy loading then Hibernate will Load All the Records as need into the System.